# How do I become unstuck?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

After landing on a bad place from a Sky-Line at Shanty Town, I became stuck, unable to become unstuck with movement controls, including crouching and jumping, and jumping back to the Sky-Line. At that point, I decided to restart from the last checkpoint.

If one becomes stuck, is there a '[noclip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noclip_mode)' or similar cheat or console command (for the PC), or other workarounds to become unstuck?

Comment: Jumping or ducking usually works for me. I'm sure you've tried this though...

Comment: I got the same problem and like @jmfsg I had to restart from the last checkpoint.

Comment: There's an area in the hallway in the basement of the Finkton police station, with the doors to all the cells, that you can jump behind some boxes and get stuck.  I too had to restart from the checkpoint, which is poorly located 15 minutes earlier, before a big fight :(

Comment: I haven't played Infinite, but in a few games I've played, if you try to move in one direction for an extended period of time, the engine realizes you're stuck and noclips you out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a console in Bioshock: Infinite.  There were commands (like 'ghost') that could be bound to keys in the original Bioshock, but these don't seem to work in Infinite.

Sadly, if you get stuck and can't continue, you just have to reload a checkpoint or a chapter save.

Comment: That sucks. I got stuck behind Elizabeth after exploring all of Emporia and lost about 90 minutes of progress, because checkpoints are so infrequent.